# cURL Failed to connect to port 80

Tags: php, curl, php-curl, laravel-valet

I am using cURL in my PHP script to test my API. When i try to use my function to get data it throw me an error

> Error: Failed to connect to alenke.test port 80: Connection refused

but when I execute it in the terminal

```
curl --ipv4 -v "http://alenke.test/wp-json/chatbot/v1/brand";
```

it give me

```
`Trying 127.0.0.1...
    * TCP_NODELAY set
    * Connected to alenke.test (127.0.0.1) port 80 (#0)
    GET /wp-json/chatbot/v1/brand HTTP/1.1
    Host: alenke.test
    User-Agent: curl/7.54.0
    Accept:
    HTTP/1.1 200 OK
    Server: nginx/1.15.7
    Date: Sun, 01 Sep 2019 16:47:36 GMT
    Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8
    Transfer-Encoding: chunked
    Connection: keep-alive
    Vary: Accept-Encoding
    X-Powered-By: PHP/7.3.7
    X-Robots-Tag: noindex
    Link: <http://alenke.test/wp-json/>; rel="https://api.w.org/" 
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff Access-Control-Expose-Headers: X-WP-Total, X-WP-TotalPages Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Authorization, Content-Type Allow: GET `
```

and give me all data that I need but when to execute this php script

```
function callAPI($method, $url, $data){
        $curl = curl_init();
        switch ($method){
            case "POST":
                curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
                if ($data)
                    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);
                break;
            case "PUT":
                curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "PUT");
                if ($data)
                    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);
                break;
            default:
                if ($data)
                    $url = sprintf("%s?%s", $url, http_build_query($data));
        }
        // OPTIONS:
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
            'Content-Type: application/json',
        ));
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPAUTH, CURLAUTH_BASIC);
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_USERPWD, "admin:admin");
        // EXECUTE:
        $result = curl_exec($curl);
        if(!$result){
            if (curl_errno($curl)) {
                echo 'Error: ' . curl_error($curl);      
                echo'//;
                echo print_r(curl_getinfo($curl));   
                echo'//;
                die("Connection Failure..?");
            }
        }
        curl_close($curl);
        return $result;
    }
```

it shows me this error

> Error: Failed to connect to alenke.test port 80: Connection refused

Comment: First from your terminal local execute telnet alenke.test 80

Comment: i'am using mac is telnet work on mac or thare is another way to make sure is alenke.test on port 80 is working well

Comment: I am sorry for my little info about telnet now i'am download it and i will try what U wrote and i will comment with outbut

Comment: OK , but you must to try in the same computer where you deploy your scripts php...because the error is clair >   Failed to connect to alenke.test port 80: Connection refused

Comment: now trying to execute `telnet alenke.test 80 `give me that `Trying 127.0.0.1...
Connected to alenke.test.
Escape character is '^]'.
Connection closed by foreign host.`

Comment: alenke.test is in your localhost?....then turn of you firewall

Comment: Yes , I'am using valet for development enviroment and it works will and before that error it work vary well

Comment: I turn of firewall it give me same error i can't figure out what the error ):

Answer (score 0):

I've copy-pasted your code to a file (test.php) on my computer, surrounded it with a
`<?php .. ?>`
block, and added a call like this after the function:

`$res=callAPI('GET', 'http://myserver/', '');
echo $res;`

Then started the script in command line by `php test.php`, and got the expected result (the index.html file of my server).

So whatever you're doing works. Try testing it in command line first to see if necessary modules are installed/enabled. If it works that way, try to fix your webserver's config files. If you need more help, please add some information about your system (webserver, version, OS, and anything relevant). Sysadmins tend to disable certain features (including curl) on shared hosting, maybe your default configuration is based on that.

Comment: I already have this code after the function  <br> `$brands = callAPI('GET','http://alenke.test/wp-json/chatbot/v1/brand',false);
$brands = json_decode($brands,true);

echo $brands;`
<br> and it already work before but when i come back to run it it give me that error above<br> I am using mac and valet with webserver nginx

Comment: If I understand it correctly from a quick search, valet uses a virtual machine (Laravel Homestead), so it might disable outgoing requests. But I don't have/use any Macs, so I can't help you further. Your code is good (I've tested it), the bug is in your environment.

Comment: the crazy things it had work well yesterday and Now it give me errors

Answer (score 0):

I will recommend you check your firewall and to check if the domain what ip is resolving.

```
telnet domain 80
telnet ipserver 80
```

Comment: I turn of firewall it give me same error `Trying 127.0.0.1...
Connected to localhost.
Escape character is '^]'.
Connection closed by foreign host.`

Comment: @MohammedAlama that is not an error, that is a success, ie telnet did connect to your box.  Did you try in your curl to give the url "127.0.0.1" ?  curious

Comment: no because i'am using valet and this is the url i'am using for referring to the site